# Distorted Noise: Size smaller than 0.0001

Tags: modeling, texturing, texture-painting, displacement, texture-coordinates

I used a `Displace` modifier with a `Distorted Noise`, so it's working fine but when I try to set its size smaller than 0.0001, it doesn't change and keeps at the 0.0001 value. Here are the screenshots:

**"Size" value of the `Distorted Noise` texture set to 0.0001 (it's shown as 0.000 in the UI because of precision limitations):**

[image]

**Trying to change it to 0.00002:**

[image]

I hit Enter and then click on the editbox but it's not changed:

[image]

How do I fix that and use lower sizes (or should I use another way like texture nodes to scale that down?)?

Comment: Hello :). I think you're right about the precision limitations. I believe using nodes (*Displacement Map* and *Multiply*) gives better control over such fine details...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your issue is Texture Size value, but not enough geometry of your object. Try to use SubSurf modifier before Displacement modifier.

[image]

BTW for such a small details I would use noise texture as Bump Map or for Microdisplacement.

Note: Quite strange for me is that textures for Displacement are different than for shaders - there is not this texture. On other hand, Noise texture node use opposite scale values, like 10000 for similar 0.0001 of Distortion Noise. And with node there in not problem set 1.000.000 :)

Comment: I think its detail is enough and the problem is floating-point precision (I think). Anyway, I'll check that.

Comment: @vklidu I think shader *Noise Texture* is a [Perlin Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise), while *texture presets* use a *Gaussian White noise* (since 2.81 also available in shaders)

Comment: @Jachym Michal : Shader - yes, *Distorted Noise* use more types - *Blender Original* by default (White Noise is presented separately as Noise). My confusion comes from two lists of textures https://imgur.com/TTiOCHc

Comment: @vklidu I alreay had SubSurf, so I increased its resolution, so the noise became smaller but still I can't change the value to lower than 0.0001. I think it's a floating-point precision limitation. Thanks

Comment: Please share your blend. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com